# Laravel 5.1 Database Seeding not working

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-seeding

I have got some problem with Seeding. I create new seed file:

```
php artisan make:seeder RoleUserSeeder
```

i run method i added:

```
DB::table('role_user')->insert([
    'role_id' => 1,
    'user_id' => 2,
]);
```

and then try:
`php artisan optimize`
Generating optimized class loader
`php artisan db:seed`

but they do not add record in role_user table

I do not have any errors

Thanks for help

Comment: I know about it. i tried `php artisan db:seed --class=RoleUserSeeder` but they not working. In `DatabaseSeeder` i added `$this->call(RoleUserSeeder::class);` and they still not working

Comment: Have you run composer dumpautoload?

Comment: I forget about it. Now it works. Thanks for help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `$this->call(RoleUserSeeder::class);` in your `DatabaseSeeder` class (located in `/database/seeds`).

Comment: It does not work, but when i copy `DB::table('role_user')->insert([
    'role_id' => 1,
    'user_id' => 2,
]);` to DatabaseSeeder it works

Comment: Do you get an error message when you use `$this->call`?

Comment: No errors but when i added `echo "test"` before call i saw this text, after call no